# Two supposedly same variables somehow hold different values

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

I am testing an I2C protocol with an STM32 microcontroller. I made a function that should read 16-bit content of a register within the slave device the microcontroller will be talking to. My question does not really revolve around the hardware, but of two variables (one returned by the function while the other modified by the function through a pointer argument).

Here is the function:

```
uint16_t __SimpleReadRegister(uint8_t cRegAddress, uint16_t *pRxBuff)
{
    /* Transmit the register address to read from to the IC - register address is 1 byte */
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, SLAVEDEVICE_ADDRESS, &cRegAddress, 1, i2cTimeout);
    
    uint8_t tempRxBuff[2];
    uint8_t retval;
    
    /* Receive 2 bytes (contents of cRegAddress register from the IC */
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, SLAVEDEVICE_ADDRESS, (uint8_t*)tempRxBuff, 2, i2cTimeout);
    
    retval = (tempRxBuff[1] << 8) | tempRxBuff[0];            // BREAKPOINT 1 PLACED HERE
    *pRxBuff = (tempRxBuff[1] << 8) | tempRxBuff[0];          // BREAKPOINT 2 PLACED HERE
    
    return retval;
}
```

Here is a portion of the main function:

```
uint16_t status1 = 0x0000;
uint16_t status2 = 0xFFFF;
status2 = __SimpleReadRegister(0x00, &status1);
printf("0x%04X, 0x%04X\n\n", (unsigned int)(status1 & 0xFFFF), (unsigned int)(status2 & 0xFFFF));
```

What is printed out here is:
status1 = 0x0319, status2 = 0x0019 
even though I assumed they both should be the same value. `status1` is basically passed as a pointer into the function, which was assigned after `status2` was assigned a value. At BREAKPOINT1: `tempRxBuff[0] = 0x19` and `tempRxBuff[1] = 0x03`, which means that status2 holds the wrong value.

What could be the reason why `status1` is holding the wrong value here? I also tried placing a delay after `HAL_I2C_Master_Receive()` but it did not change the outcome.

Thanks!

Comment: You showed the definition of `__SimpleReadRegsiter()` but you're calling `__FuelGauge_SimpleReadRegister()`.  Show the definition of `__FuelGauge_SimpleReadRegister()`.  Does it return uint8_t instead of uint16_t?

Comment: @kkrambo I edited __FuelGauge_SimpleReadRegister() and changed its name to __SimpleReadRegister() but forgot to change the name in the main function. I made an edit in regards to that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have retval declared as a uint8_t within the function.  When you make the assignment to retval, the most significant byte gets masked off leaving only the least significant byte.  Then only the least significant byte is returned.

Change retval to a uint16_t.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I changed it to `uint16_t` and its the same now.

Answer (score 1):

`retval` is 8 bits long and it will hold only `tempRxBuff[0]` value

`*pRxBuff` is 16 bits long and it will hold the value of `tempRxBuff[1] << 8) | tempRxBuff[0];`

They can be the same if **`tempRxBuff[1] == tempRxBuff[0]`**

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. Got used to returning variables as `uint8_t`. Thanks for pointing it out!